# SSH from Synology NAS to remote server

Tags: ssh, remote-access, synology

When I run competitions for Icelandic Horses, I want to automatically upload the results from our Synology NAS to a remote webserver. The program we use automatically generates the html-files that needs to be uploaded.

What is the easiest way to achieve this? I have SSH access on both the NAS and the webserver.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can create a cron task in the synology console with the command:

```
sudo -i
vi /etc/crontab
```

Edit the file and add a line like this at the end of the file with a scp command:

```
0 0 * * * root scp -r "-i/root/.ssh/mykey" 'root@serverurl.com:/some/remote/path' '/some/local/path'
```

Finally you have to reload the configuration restarting the service with:

```
synoservice -restart crond
```

Before all this you must to configure a pair keys to [avoid the password entry](https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=98905):

- cd to a private directory of the user which will be running the script (typically "$HOME/.ssh", to be created if needed). That directory must be protected to write acces from other users, fix the modes if needed.
- generate the keypair using command "ssh-keygen"
  ("/usr/syno/bin/ssh-keygen" if not in your PATH)
- at the prompt "Enter file in which to save the key", choose a file
  name (let's say "mykey")
- at the prompt "Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):" press
  return (this will create a passwordless private key)
- Two files will be created: "mykey" and "mykey.pub"
- copy the contents of mykey.pub inside "$HOME/.ssh/authorized_key"
  file of user account on the remote machine your script is going to
  connect to.
- in your script, add "-i" as argument to the
  ssh command

Also in this forum is explained how to make the copy with rsync instead of scp